# How to embed mercury in new action without losing ability to use select fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, wysiwyg, mercury-editor

I want to use the Mercury editor that was presented in railscast lately => http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor but Ive got a problem with it. I have a model that contains several fields that need to be selected. So I cant use Mercury in the `new` action because the new action contains much more then the `content` field which is a describing text of my Object.

So what I want to do is embed mercury into the new/edit action to use it as a WYSIWYG Editor but I also want to be able to submit it and change the values of my dropdowns and token inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am pretty sure that this is not the use case for mercury... if i understand what you are asking you should have an page settings new/edit actions, then use the show to do the mercury editing.